# Sort the items in the combobox in vb net

Tags: asp.net, combobox

I have a populate a combobox with values from Oracle, when finish populate add another item, then I try to sort the fields into combo such the firt field display is the data adding manually.
This code below:

```
        CboPlazasComisiones.DataSource = GlobaldtPlace(ConSale:=True)
        CboPlazasComisiones.DataBind()
        CboPlazasComisiones.Items.Add(New ListItem("ALL", "-1")) //When the user click the combo, I need to apper in the first position the item ALL.
        CboPlazasComisiones.Enabled = True
        CboPlazasComisiones.SelectedValue = "-1"
```

Comment: Personally I would sort the datasource ( GlobaldtPlace return value before binding it to the ComboBox)

Answer (score 0):

Personally when I did this (I'm assuming this is a WebForm page).
I put the "ALL" option into the page defition then within my Page_Load I read the real options out of my database and appended them to the control.

This would require you to put an Adapter between your DataSource and the control though.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CboPlazasComisiones" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="ALL"/>
</asp:DropDownList>


CboPlazasComisiones.Items.AddRange(GlobaldtPlace(ConSale:=True))
```