# Sorting ComboBox Items from bound DataSource

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sorting, combobox, bindingsource

I've been trying over and over again to get my `ComboBox` items to sort correctly, but nothing I do seems to work. I've looked at a number of SO topics with various suggestions for making it work but no matter what I try, every time I load my form, the items in my `ComboBox` will not be sorted. Here's the basic code I'm using to populate the `ComboBox`:

```vb
'ClaimCodes is a class-level variable
Private ClaimCodes As DataTable

Private Sub LoadCodeComboBoxes()
    Dim CodeTable As DataTable
    Dim DescriptionTable As DataTable
    Dim DescriptionBinding As New BindingSource
    Dim CodeBinding As New BindingSource

    Using MyDB As New DbConnection("my connection string")
        ClaimCodes = MyDB.ExecuteStatement("SELECT code, descr FROM code_table WHERE code > 0")
    End Using

    CodeTable = ClaimCodes.Copy
    CodeTable.DefaultView.Sort = "code ASC"
    CodeTable = CodeTable.DefaultView.ToTable

    DescriptionTable = ClaimCodes.Copy
    DescriptionTable.DefaultView.Sort = "descr ASC"
    DescriptionTable = DescriptionTable.DefaultView.ToTable

    CodeBinding.DataSource = CodeTable
    CodeBinding.Sort = "code"

    DescriptionBinding.DataSource = DescriptionTable
    DescriptionBinding.Sort = "descr"

    With Me.cboClaimCode
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .Items.Clear()
        .DataSource = CodeBinding
        .ValueMember = "code"
        .DisplayMember = "code"
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With

    With Me.cboClaimCodeDescription
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .Items.Clear()
        .DataSource = DescriptionBinding
        .ValueMember = "code"
        .DisplayMember = "descr"
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried various iterations of the above, including:

- Removed the `BindingSource` objects completely and directly used the `XXXTable.DefaultView`
- Apply the `Sort` at the `DataTable` level, the `BindingSource` level, and both
- Changing the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ComboBox` to display an item instead of setting it to `-1` (unselected)
- Changing the order of the `ComboBox` property setting so that the `DataSource` is set before/after the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`
- Setting the `.Sorted` property of the `ComboBox` to true (*of course, that throws an exception because the object is bound to the `DataSource`*)

The `ClaimCodes` `DataTable` (*before any sorting has been applied*) has 17 rows:

```
+---------------------+
| code |    descr     |
+---------------------+
| 10   | <code desc>  |
| 11   | <code desc>  |
| 13   | <code desc>  |
| 14   | <code desc>  |
| 15   | <code desc>  |
| 30   | <code desc>  |
| 35   | <code desc>  |
| 99   | <code desc>  |
| 1    | <code desc>  |
| 36   | <code desc>  |
| 54   | <code desc>  |
| 60   | <code desc>  |
| 29   | <code desc>  |
| 61   | <code desc>  |
| 50   | <code desc>  |
| 71   | <code desc>  |
| 70   | <code desc>  |
+---------------------+
```

After I apply sorting, I can check the object (*`DataTable` and/or `BindingSource`*) and look at the results in the **Watch** window. From there, they show sorted as expected (*1, 10, 11, etc.*). However, when the form is displayed, the items in the `ComboBox` are *not* sorted and show up in the same order as the original, unsorted `DataTable` (*10, 11, 13, etc.*).

Just a few examples of SO questions I've looked at for inspiration:

- [Sort string items in a datatable as int using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7572685/2569697) (*doesn't really apply b/c I've verified that the values are stored in the `DataTable` as `System.Int32`*)
- [Sort the items in the combobox in vb net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23018900/2569697)
- [Sort combobox items from datasource (GetScheme("Tables")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46582235/2569697)
- [how to sort data in my combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10743194/2569697)
- [Sort combobox alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26820188/2569697)
- [how to sorting item in combo box by Alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60898128/2569697)

I feel like I'm probably overlooking something really simple/stupid, but I've gone over and over this with no progress and can't figure out why. What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

One other thing that I *just* thought of which *might* have something to do with this: These `ComboBox`es have the following properties:

- **DrawMode:** `OwnerDrawFixed`
- **DropDownStyle:** `DropDownList`
- **FlatStyle:** `System`
- **FormattingEnabled:** `True`

Not sure if `OwnerDrawFixed` might have something to do with it, but I'm using that to be able to implement a custom `.DrawItem` event handler to highlight the `ComboBox` when it's selected.

---

### QUICK UPDATE:

I switched the `DrawMode` on one of the `ComboBox`es back to `Normal` and tried again, but the items were still "unsorted". It doesn't appear that that is the cause of the issue.

---

### ADDITIONAL CODE:

As mentioned, I'm using a custom `DrawItem` handler for the `ComboBox`es for visual styling when it's selected. Here's the code for that event handler, which is basically reused on each of the `ComboBox`es:

```vb
Private Sub cboClaimCode_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboClaimCode.DrawItem
    Dim ComboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim ComboBoxFont As Font = ComboBox.Font
    Dim ComboBoxColor As Color
    Dim TextColor As Color
    Dim ComboBoxBounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    Dim TextBrush As SolidBrush
    Dim ComboBoxBrush As SolidBrush

    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        TextColor = SystemColors.WindowText
        ComboBoxColor = Colors.PaleBlue
    Else
        TextColor = SystemColors.WindowText
        ComboBoxColor = SystemColors.Window
    End If

    TextBrush = New SolidBrush(TextColor)
    ComboBoxBrush = New SolidBrush(ComboBoxColor)

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ComboBoxBrush, ComboBoxBounds)

    If e.Index >= 0 Then
        If Not IsCellEmpty(ClaimCodes(e.Index)("code")) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ClaimCodes(e.Index)("code").ToString, ComboBoxFont, TextBrush, New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't duplicate your issue.  Tried to mimic your code table and data and binding and my ComboBox is sorted: 1, 10, 11,13 ...

Comment: Remove all DefaultViews clutter and `Items.Clear()` (?), just `dim CodeBinding = new BindingSource(ClaimCodes.Copy(), Nothing) CodeBinding.Sort = "code"`. Set the DisplayMember, ValueMember, then the DataSource to the BindingSource. If it *doesn't work*, then your Columns are not of the expected Type or you have other code the messes with this

Comment: @LarsTech - Thank you for that. Quick question: at what point did you execute the ComboBox loading code? I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the fact that I'm executing it during the form's `Load` event...

Comment: I had it in the constructor, but moving it to the load method was no different.  You have something else going on.  Try duplicating this issue in a new project.

Comment: @LarsTech & @Jimi - Looks like I found it. The problem appears to have been introduced with my custom `DrawItem` handler because I was referencing the unsorted version of the `DataTable` (`ClaimCodes`) when drawing the `ComboBox` items. I'll add some more code to this question and then post an answer that explains what I've found in a bit.

Comment: Why would you need any DataTable when performing custom drawing of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### "FINAL" UPDATED CODE TO INCORPORATE SUGGESTIONS FROM ORIGINAL COMMENTS

Now that I was able to find the cause of the unexpected behavior, I've gone back and done some code clean-up to incorporate the suggestions made by @Jimi. I've removed the class-level `DataTable` objects entirely and gotten rid of all the `DefaultView` "clutter" in the `LoadCodeComboBoxes()` method (***NOTE:** I've fully qualified most of the object types, just for the sake of absolute clarity. Feel free to remove the "extraneous" namespaces as needed.*):

```vb
Private Sub LoadCodeComboBoxes()
    Dim CodeTable As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim DescriptionBinding As BindingSource
    Dim CodeBinding As BindingSource

    Using MyDB As New DbConnection("my connection string")
        CodeTable = MyDB.ExecuteStatement("SELECT code, descr FROM code_table WHERE code > 0")
    End Using

    CodeBinding = New BindingSource(CodeTable.Copy, Nothing) With {.Sort = "code ASC"}
    DescriptionBinding = New BindingSource(CodeTable.Copy, Nothing) With {.Sort = "descr ASC"}

    With Me.cboClaimCode
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .DisplayMember = "code"
        .ValueMember = "code"
        .DataSource = CodeBinding
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With

    With Me.cboClaimCodeDescription
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .DisplayMember = "descr"
        .ValueMember = "code"
        .DataSource = DescriptionBinding
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With
End Sub
```

Also, by eliminating the class-level `DataTable`s and taking the suggestion to use the event argument's properties, I was able to create a more "generic" event handler that I can assign to any `ComboBox`:

```vb
Public Sub DrawComboBoxItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs)
    If TypeOf (sender) Is System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox Then
        Dim ComboBox As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)
        Dim ComboBoxColor As System.Drawing.Color
        Dim TextColor As System.Drawing.Color

        If (e.State And System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemState.Selected) = System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemState.Selected Then
            TextColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText
            ComboBoxColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
        Else
            TextColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText
            ComboBoxColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
        End If

        Using TextBrush As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(TextColor)
            Using ComboBoxBrush As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(ComboBoxColor)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ComboBoxBrush, e.Bounds)

                If e.Index >= 0 Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(ComboBox.GetItemText(ComboBox.Items(e.Index)),
                                      e.Font,
                                      TextBrush,
                                      New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

*This also incorporates the `Using` statement for the `SolidBrush` objects so that they are disposed of properly within the method.*

With that in place, I removed all of the individual in-form event handlers (`cboClaimCode_DrawItem`, etc.) and just assigned them in a method that applies other event handlers:

```vb
Private Sub AddFormControlHandlers()
    AddHandler Me.cboClaimCode.DrawItem, AddressOf DrawComboBoxItem
    AddHandler Me.cboClaimCodeDescription.DrawItem, AddressOf DrawComboBoxItem
    [...]
End Sub
```

I hope that helps anyone else looking for how to populate their `ComboBox`es. Thank you again, @Jimi and @LarsTech for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LarsTech and @Jimi for their comments which helped lead me to find what the problem was. As I was testing, I also noticed that the selections weren't working exactly as expected either (*I hadn't noticed that before*), so that and their comments pointed me in a different direction altogether. This is basically a "rough draft" of the solution I threw together to get it working. Take a look at my other, accepted answer for a "cleaned-up" version of the code that incorporates suggestions from the comments.

As mentioned in the question, I've got a custom `DrawItem` event handler for these `ComboBox`es. That event handler was referencing the "original", unsorted `DataTable` to add some UX "prettification" for the users to be able to more easily identify when the `ComboBox` is selected (*without it, the users were having difficulty seeing when the box was in focus*).

To address this, I moved the `DataTable`s that were used by the `ComboBox`es up to the class-level instead of within the method:

```
Public Class MyForm
    Private ClaimCodes As DataTable
    Private ClaimCodeDescriptions As DataTable
    [...]
End Class
```

(*yes, I reused the `ClaimCodes` object name from before*)

Then I changed my `LoadCodeComboBoxes()` method to fill those class-level `DataTable` objects instead of method-local objects:

```vb
Private Sub LoadCodeComboBoxes()
    Dim CodeTable As DataTable
    Dim DescriptionBinding As New BindingSource
    Dim CodeBinding As New BindingSource

    Using MyDB As New DbConnection("my connection string")
        CodeTable = MyDB.ExecuteStatement("SELECT code, descr FROM code_table WHERE code > 0")
    End Using

    ClaimCodes = CodeTable.Copy
    ClaimCodes.DefaultView.Sort = "code ASC"
    ClaimCodes = ClaimCodes.DefaultView.ToTable

    ClaimCodeDescriptions = CodeTable.Copy
    ClaimCodeDescriptions.DefaultView.Sort = "descr ASC"
    ClaimCodeDescriptions = ClaimCodeDescriptions.DefaultView.ToTable

    CodeBinding.DataSource = ClaimCodes
    CodeBinding.Sort = "code"

    DescriptionBinding.DataSource = ClaimCodeDescriptions
    DescriptionBinding.Sort = "descr"

    With Me.cboClaimCode
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .DisplayMember = "code"
        .ValueMember = "code"
        .DataSource = CodeBinding
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With

    With Me.cboClaimCodeDescription
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .DisplayMember = "descr"
        .ValueMember = "code"
        .DataSource = DescriptionBinding
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, I updated my `DrawItem` event handlers to use the individual class-level `DataTable`s:

```vb
Private Sub cboClaimCodeDescription_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboClaimCodeDescription.DrawItem
    Dim ComboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim ComboBoxFont As Font = ComboBox.Font
    Dim ComboBoxColor As Color
    Dim TextColor As Color
    Dim ComboBoxBounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    Dim TextBrush As SolidBrush
    Dim ComboBoxBrush As SolidBrush

    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        TextColor = SystemColors.WindowText
        ComboBoxColor = Colors.Blue
    Else
        TextColor = SystemColors.WindowText
        ComboBoxColor = SystemColors.Window
    End If

    TextBrush = New SolidBrush(TextColor)
    ComboBoxBrush = New SolidBrush(ComboBoxColor)

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ComboBoxBrush, ComboBoxBounds)

    If e.Index >= 0 Then
        If Not IsCellEmpty(ClaimCodeDescriptions(e.Index)("descr")) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ClaimCodeDescriptions(e.Index)("descr").ToString, ComboBoxFont, TextBrush, New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now that each is using its own, sorted `DataTable`, everything seems to be working exactly as expected.